# Are there missable achievements in The Walking Dead season 2?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-two

I just got The Walking Dead season 2 and I would like to know if there are missable achievements. I remember there have been a few in other Telltale games including season 1, and was just curious before I start playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to an answer on Steam, **there are no missable achievements**. The link does include some mild spoilers about the achievements, so do not click it without thinking: [source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/261030/discussions/0/34096318958643982/).